# Searching a whole Datagrid for a Value

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am looking to prevent a User from adding a country to a Database if the country already appears in the Datagrid.

The Datagrid is pre-loaded with the countries on the form load event.

I have the following code (below) however i get an error stating that the subscript is out of range and can't be negative.

```
Dim appear As Integer
Dim colcount As Integer
Dim rowcount As Integer
colcount = all_countries.ColumnCount
rowcount = all_countries.RowCount
For i = 0 To rowcount
  For j = 0 To colcount
    If (new_country.Text = all_countries.Item(colcount, rowcount).Value) Then
      MsgBox("Country Exists", 0)
      appear = 1
    End If
  Next
Next
```

Comment: It's way simpler if you search it using the datatable and not the datagrid. For Each d as DataRow in datatable.Rows If d("Country) = ...

Comment: Besides what OwerFlov states, you are enumaerating up to ColumnCount and RowCount when you should be iterating up to ColumnCount -1 and RowCount -1 since they are 0 based indices.  And don't you have just one column for country?  Why have to search through all columns for it?

Comment: @OwerFlov: +1. You should never perform validation directly in the UI element. Another thought is that you could have had unique key constraint defined on that underlying table. Then there is no code. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`CellValidating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx) event, e.g.:

```
Private Sub all_countries_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles all_countries.CellValidating
    Dim headerText = all_countries.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText
    ' Abort validation if cell is not in the country column '
    If Not headerText.Equals("Country") Then Return

    ' Confirm that the cell is not empty '
    Dim thisCountry As String = e.FormattedValue.ToString()
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(thisCountry) Then
        all_countries.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Country must not be empty"
        e.Cancel = True
    Else
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In all_countries.Rows
            If row.Index <> e.RowIndex Then
                Dim countryCell = row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex)
                If thisCountry = countryCell.FormattedValue.ToString() Then
                    all_countries.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Country must be unique"
                    e.Cancel = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: im not so sure of this. i do not let the user add directly into the Datagrid. they enter their country in the text box (new_country) and then submit via the button. the code in the original post is on the button click event.

Comment: @user1662306: Does that matter? Pick the code above where i search the grid for a given value. However, normally you should prefer to search the underlying datasource(e.g. a database).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Dim X as Integer
For X = 0 to DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
   If DataGridView.Rows(X).Cells("ColumnName").Value = new_country.Text Then
      MsgBox("Country Exists", 0)
      appear = 1
   End If
Next
```

Note: "Count - 1". I think that might be what is causing an issue in your code. I hope this helps